# How to get the outlook calendar events of other user in the same organization through graph api?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Am working on Microsoft Graph Api to get the outlook calendar events of other user in the organization. I wrote the code like,

`var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Calendar.Events .Request() .Select("subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location") .GetAsync();`

when am trying to get other user events am getting the error like access denied where as the same code is working for getting "me" events.I also added necessary permissions

From that issue I understood that am getting the error because it is not taking the scopes correctly. am expecting the code that takes the scopes that were added in app registration.

Answer (score 0):

With the delegate authentication flows there are two types of permission you would need the first is the oAuth permission to access shared calendar Calendars.Read.Shared or Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared these need to be consented to as well. Then the user that your using needs to have delegate permission to the calendar folder themselves (eg they have to be able to access the target calendar folder in Outlook or Outlook on the web) this isn't enabled by default (eg people get free busy permissions by default) so for the query your trying to make you would need at least Reviewer access to the that folder